# LocalSettings.php not readable even if I set permission to 777

Tags: mediawiki

I'm on a freshly installed fedora 21. I am using mediawiki 1.24.1 and created the LocalSettings.php file through the installation page. I have also chown -R apache:apache the mediawiki folder.

However, when I try to open the actual wiki the page says 'LocalSettings.php not readable' even if I set the permission of LocalSettings.php to 777

Comment: MW from package or tarball? Where did you put the package, exactly?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue and resolved this by running the following command:

```
sudo restorecon -r /var/www/wiki/
```

It seems like SELinux was blocking us for some reason. `restorecon` is very safe and basically resets the security context of the files.

Make sure you set the permissions back to a safer value:

```
sudo chmod 644 /var/www/wiki/LocalSettings.php
```

Comment: I always forget about SELinux - I always get wonky behavior and find out SELinux is who is doing it. Thanks! This just saved me from hours of Googling.

Comment: When it doubt, blame SELinux.