# LocalSettings.php not readable. correct file permissions and try again

Tags: php, ubuntu, mediawiki

I tried to install [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) on `Ubuntu 14.04` by following [this page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Running_MediaWiki_on_Ubuntu#Configure_MediaWiki). After configuring MediaWiki,installer generated `LocalSettings.php file` and I download it. Then I put it in the base of my wiki installation (the same directory as index.php, that has `images` and  `skins` directories). Then I browse to `http://localhost/mediawiki/mediawiki-1.26.2/index.php` but I got this error:

> MediaWiki 1.26.2
>
> LocalSettings.php not readable.
>
> Please correct file permissions and try again.

How I can solve this error?

Note:

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31257401/1043882) but it does not work for me.

Comment: What does `ls -l LocalSettings.php` tell you?

Comment: @miken32 the result is: `-rw-r----- 1 ********** ********** 4673 Jan 22 22:27 LocalSettings.php`

Comment: Well unless your web server is somehow running as user `**********` you're not going to have much luck. Please correct file permissions and try again.

Comment: @miken32 How I can change permissions? I'm new user of Ubuntu. Also I replace my user name with `**********` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error says, you need to correct the file permissions.

```
sudo chown www-data LocalSettings.php
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention.